# How to add an item to list in setter and notify one by one with provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add a TaskModel to taskModelList in setter method and then notify which I encounter the bellow error. I know changing the type of setter parameter to List will fix the issue, but is it possible to add a single item to list in set method?

**Error:**

> The return type of getter 'taskModelList' is 'List' which
> isn't a subtype of the type 'TaskModel' of its setter 'taskModelList'.

**Code:**

```
class TaskViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<TaskModel> _taskModelList = [];

  set taskModelList(TaskModel taskModel) {
    _taskModelList.add(taskModel);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<TaskModel> get taskModelList => _taskModelList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setter currently doesn't set the `List`, rather than adding a new item in it. A setter sets the `List` with a `List` value,

```dart
set taskModelList(List<TaskModel> taskModelList) {
    _taskModelList = taskModelList;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Remove your `setter`.
If you just want to add a single item use a custom method

```dart
  void addItem(TaskModel task) {
    _taskModelList.add(task)
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

If you are using `Provider`, I would suggest enriching your `TaskViewModel` with adding a static `of` method:

```dart
 static TaskViewModel of(BuildContext context, {bool listen = false}) {
    return Provider.of<TaskViewModel>(context, listen: listen);
  }
```

Then you can easily listen for changes

```dart
TaskViewModel.of(context, listen: true).taskModelList
```

Comment: Updated also the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if there is a way to solve this with getter and setter.

Comment: Hi, like esentis answered correctly, you need a List as parameter for the setter. You could try to use .addAll() to add all entries of the list inside setter.
But this would be confusing. So please **don't** do that!

Answer (score 2):

@esentis answer is correct, but it should also be noted that getters and setters are usually not necessary in Dart.

As per the [Dart Style Guide](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_getters_setters.html)

*AVOID wrapping fields in getters and setters just to be "safe".
In Java and C#, it's common to hide all fields behind getters and setters (or properties in C#), even if the implementation just forwards to the field. That way, if you ever need to do more work in those members, you can do it without needing to touch the callsites. This is because calling a getter method is different than accessing a field in Java, and accessing a property isn't binary-compatible with accessing a raw field in C#.
Dart doesn't have this limitation. Fields and getters/setters are completely indistinguishable. You can expose a field in a class and later wrap it in a getter and setter without having to touch any code that uses that field.*

GOOD:

```
class Box {
  var contents;
}
```

BAD:

```
class Box {
  var _contents;
  get contents => _contents;
  set contents(value) {
    _contents = value;
  }
}
```